# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{1/k} = L^{1/k}$.

Tags: limits, analysis

Suppose that ${a_n}$ is a convergent sequence of positive terms that converges to $L \geq 0$. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{1/k} = L^{1/k}$ .

- I know I'll have $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_n > 0$. I also know I'll have $|a^{1/k}_n - L^{1/k}| < \varepsilon$ and also $a_n - L = (a_n^{1/k})^k - (L^{1/k})^k$. This is as far as I have been able to get, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Observe this identity : $(a^k - b^k) = (a-b)(a^{k-1} + a^{k-2}b + a^{k-3}b^2 + \cdots + ab^{k-2} + b^{k-1})$.

Then what about $(a-b) = (a^{\frac{1}{k}} - b^{\frac{1}{k}})(\cdots)$ and so $(a^{\frac{1}{k}} - b^{\frac{1}{k}}) = \frac{a-b}{\cdots}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  $x \mapsto x^{1/k}$ is continuous

Comment: When proving $x^{1/k}$ is continuous, similar problem arises.

Comment: @Han Not exactly. You can use that if $f$ is strictly increasing on an interval and continuous, then $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. Apply this to $x \mapsto x^k$.